# Loop through jquery data() object to get keys and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I have a `data()` object containing some json.

Is there a way I can loop through the object and grab each parts key and value?

This is what I have so far:

```
function getFigures() {

var propertyValue = getUrlVars()["propertyValue"];

$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'calculator.php?value=' + propertyValue, function(data) {

    figures = data.figures;
    $.each(figures, function(index, figure) {

        $('#figureList').append('<li> index = ' + data.figures.figure + '</li>');

    });

});

$('#figureList').listview('refresh');

}
```

The json looks like this:

```
{"figures":{"value":"150000","completion":"10.00","coal":"32.40","local":"144.00","bacs":"35.00","landRegistry":"200.00","solFee":"395.00","vatOnSolFees":79,"stampDuty":1500,"total":2395.4}}
```

Apologies if its simple, I'm new to jQuery and couldn't find anything on SO that helped.

Comment: What do you expect to get inside `#figureList`?

Comment: Try this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `key` and `value` like this

```
$.each(data.figures, function(key, val) {

        console.log('Key: ' + key + '  Val: ' + val)

    });​
```

So change your code to

```
 $('#figureList').append('<li>'+ index + ' = ' + figure + '</li>');
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/ERAgu/

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `index` and `figure` contains the parameter name and value. I think that you want to concatenate the parameters into the string:

```
$('#figureList').append('<li>' + index + ' = ' + figure + '</li>');
```

---

An alternative is to create the list item element and set the text of it, that would also work if the text contains any characters that need encoding:

```
$('#figureList').append($('<li/>').text(index + ' = ' + figure));
```

Comment: Sir, in first one, the starting `li` have `>` missing .

Comment: @Joy: Yes, you are right, it got lost in the editing. Fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFigures() {

   var propertyValue = getUrlVars()["propertyValue"];

   $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'calculator.php?value=' + propertyValue, function(data) {

       $.each(data['figures'], function(index, val) {

          here grab "val" is key 

          $.each(data['figures'][index], function(col, valc) {

           here grab "col" is value

          }
       }

   }
```

bye